# What is playback volume?

Tags: playback

This may be a stupid question but I'm not very sure what playback volume is. Can someone please explain to me what it is what it does? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It controls how loud you want the playback to be. By playback we mean pre-recorded material (it was recorded first and now you 'play (it) back').

Comment: I should I have figured. That is what it meant. Thank you.